# jquery add variable in img src

Tags: jquery

I have some images created with php and i want to put each of them inside a li. Here is my working code :

```
        for ( i = 0; i < MaxNum; i++) {
            $('li#' + i + '').html('<img src="http://www.address.com/somephp.php?Num=1" />')
        }
```

All i want to do now is put the i variable in the the image source in order to have something like this:

```
            for ( i = 0; i < MaxNum; i++) {
            $('li#' + i + '').html('<img src="http://www.address.com/somephp.php?Num="+i />')
```

This code is not working. Is it possible to that with this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for ( i = 0; i < MaxNum; i++) {
 $('li#' + i).html('<img src="http://www.address.com/somephp.php?Num='+ i +'" />')
}
```

**Problem to you code**

`'<img src="http://www.address.com/somephp.php?Num="+i />'` in this code `i` is treated as **String**, not a variable.

#### Not a problem but better

to remove `+ ''` part from `$('li#' + i + '')`.

Answer (score 2):

The i is still inside your string, you need something like this:

```
for ( i = 0; i < MaxNum; i++) {
  $('li#' + i + '').html('<img src="http://www.address.com/somephp.php?Num='+i+'" />');
}
```

Comment: This will not work. The result will be <img src="http://www.address.com/somephp.php?Num="1" /> You need to remove the first " after Num.

Answer (score 1):

You just have quotes problems. Use this :

```
 for ( i = 0; i < MaxNum; i++) {
$('li#' + i).html('<img src="http://www.address.com/somephp.php?Num='+i+'"/>')
```

SO shows with different colors what is in strings and what isn't. Choose a text editor doing the same colorization so that those errors are more easily spotted.

I also removed the useless `+ ''` in the selector.

Answer (score 1):

```
for ( i = 0; i < MaxNum; i++) {
  $('li#' + i + '').html('<img src="http://www.address.com/somephp.php?Num="'+i+'" />');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( i = 0; i < MaxNum; i++) {
 $('li#' + i).html('<img src="http://www.address.com/somephp.php?Num='+ i +'" />')
}
```